# change mat-sidenav content dynamically from any component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to load different components in mat-sidenav from different routed components based on some action like button click?

I have created a singleton service 'SidenavService' to get reference to mat-sidenav using @ViewChild, this way I can control (like open, close, toggle etc.) sidenav from anywhere in the app.

I have also created a ng-container in mat-sidenav and stored its ViewConteinerRef in SidenavService, now in any component in component hierarchy, I can inject the SidenavService and I can use ViewConteinerRef to created embedded view.

stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-dynamic-content

Is there a better way to achieve this? loading different components in mat-sidenav from anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 14):

Experimenting with your StackBlitz, I've come up with a solution using the [portal component](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) from the Angular CDK (Component DevKit).

What I've done is to modify the original `SidenavService` code to allow a [`Portal`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#Portal) to be passed to a [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) which will emit the `Portal` to any components that have subscribed to the `Subject`. The dynamic sidenav would then have a `<ng-template>` portion inside of the sidenav with the [`cdkPortalOutlet`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#CdkPortalOutlet) attribute bound to the `Portal` `Subject`:

```html
<mat-sidenav #rightPanel position="end">
  <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="panelService.panelPortal | async"></ng-template>
</mat-sidenav>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public panelService: PanelService) { }
}
```

However, be sure to import the `PortalModule` from the `@angular/cdk/portal` entry-point into your app's module:

```js
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    PortalModule
  ],
  // ...
})
```

By allowing the `SidenavService` code to allow a `Portal` reference, you can now pass either a template reference ([`TemplateRef<T>`](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef)) or a component ([`ComponentType<T>`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/09dc4594259cf1d6b34a5a0893c0bccaa132c319/src/cdk/portal/portal.ts#L27-L30)) to the `SidenavService`. This allows for the simplification of code where there would be no need to create a dedicated component for the sidenav's dynamic content.

However, a [`TemplatePortal` (which is a `Portal` that represents an embedded template)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/09dc4594259cf1d6b34a5a0893c0bccaa132c319/src/cdk/portal/portal.ts#L116-L119) requires that a `ViewContainerRef` is specified for the second argument. In such a case, what I've done is to allow the user to specify a `ViewContainerRef` to be passed to the service where it would be used for the `TemplatePortal`.

Anyways, here's a portion of the service code. (Note: I've modified the service name to a better-sounding name: `PanelService`)

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
// ...

export class PanelService {
  /** The panel. */
  panel: MatSidenav;
  private vcr: ViewContainerRef;
  // Note: The Portal class requires that a generic is specified for the component/template type.
  private panelPortal$ = new Subject<Portal<any>>();

  get panelPortal() {
    return from(this.panelPortal$); // Or this.panelPortal$.asObservable()
  }

  setViewContainerRef(vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.vcr = vcr;
  }

  setPanelPortal(portal: Portal<any>) {
    this.panelPortal$.next(portal);
  }

  // Wrapper methods for MatSidenav go here.
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dynamic-panel) for you to play around with.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, thx. Your stackblitz doesnt work because of the flexlayout. Stackbliz now runs on ivy and apparently it has a problem. I just removed the flexlayout parts and it works.

Comment: Hey @Laker, I've fixed the issue of the StackBlitz project not running properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I'm wondering if this is the "standard" way to dinamically change the SideNav content in angular. Because it's an important requirements and I can't believe it could be done only through a (smart) hack. Does the framework nowadays implement a "native" solution for achive the same result?